How do I fix a syntax error at input in Pinescript
Hi guys can someone help me to understand what is wrong with this code ? I keep receiving the msg syntax error at input barcolor
Here's the code
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=5

indicator(title="bar color", overlay=true)

fastMA = ta.sma(close,8)
slowMA = ta.sma(close,200)

plot(fastMA, color=color.blue)
plot(slowMA, color=color.red)

if  fastMA > slowMA
   barcolor(close > close[10] ? color.yellow : color.white)

if  fastMA < slowMA  
   barcolor(close < close [10] ? color.green : color.black)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is the second time I've corrected the formatting of your post. If you make another edit, format the code properly so that we don't have to do it for you again. Also, when you get an error message, it's better to include the complete, exact error message in your post - even if it makes no sense to you, it has information that can be useful to others.

You cannot use functions like barcolor in the local scope (e.g. within an if block).
You can set your color with your conditions and then call barcolor() in the global scope.
color my_color = na

if  fastMA > slowMA
    my_color := (close > close[10]) ? color.yellow : color.white

if  fastMA < slowMA  
    my_color := (close < close [10]) ? color.green : color.black

barcolor(my_color)

